# Jumper wire solution for short header pins /

Tags: breadboard, prototyping, header, jumper

I installed header pins that fit into a feather microcontroller, but since they are not double sided header pins, the top side is too short to attach normal jumper wires to. Is there some clean, non-permanent solution to this where I can still attach jumper wires, but not solder or desolder any existing pins?

[image: header pins soldered to PCB]

Comment: Those do not give enough purchase for any crimped sockets of any reasonable price.

Comment: Related: "[Extending header pins](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/332061/101852)" - however those solutions don't match your stated requirement of no soldering.

Comment: Carefully cut each plastic section and use a flat screwdriver to lift the plastic off.

Comment: Might be a silly question. If the plan was to insert it into a breadboard, why are you planning on attaching jumpers to the headers rather than just using the breadboard?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either cut the plastic and lift it off the pins, or use test clips or micro grabber clips to attach to the remaining headers. You could also use wire wrap. Or solder a second header to that header. It's possible just ugly.

Or save the hassle and just desolder and resolder a new one of the right length. It will take you less time than hacking something.

Answer (score 1):

Desoldering seems to be the easiest.

These pins are very easy to desolder: grab them one by one with needle nose pliers, heat the other side, and pull. Once the pin is heated, it will soften the plastic and slide through with very little force. You don't need to hack the plastic. This will take like 2 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

They are soldered the wrong way around. Desolder them and solder the short end to the board.

Comment: This is true, but the OP asked for a solution which doesn't involve soldering.

Comment: True, but there won't be any permanent solution since it's just done wrong. everything else would be quite "hacky"

Comment: I assume this is a quick and dirty prototype, so "hacky" may be OK. It's not like the OP will be able to use their device for months or transport it without ruining the connections, even if they re-solder the pin header the other way around.

Answer (score 0):

These pins can be connected to jumper cables just fine if jumper cables have the right kind of connectors. Remove the black cover to see what connector you have.

Bad:

[image]

Better:

[image]

Good:

[image]

The good variety can be connected to the pins you have. The one in the middle will be on its limits, but may hold in place if you don't pull on the wires. The bad variety won't hold on anything but a full-length pin, plus it only works well once.

With the bad kind, it's sometimes possible to push the springs further down to make it temporarily better, but don't hold your breath. If you can't get your connectors to hold in place, your next solderless option is the clamp wires:

[image]

These take much more space than regular connectors and are quite unstable, but can hook up to very small pins.